# Patching a file with x64dbg after finding ram addresses

Tags: patch, ollydbg, cheat-engine, reversing, x64dbg

I've been tinkering with an exe game. After finding a memory address I wanted to change using Cheat Engine (I want to change a `je` to a `jne` op), I successfully managed to change the game's code.

I want to modify the .exe file so that when I launch the game, that `je` is already modified to a `jne`. However, I read that when editing memory in Cheat Engine, the memory modified is RAM, and therefore I cannot use any tools such as olly or x64dbg (because they modify disk memory, not RAM) to patch the exe.

I tried to find the address I found in CE at the disk file memory, but it seems as if the memory is only available after the game.exe is launched.